# What is wrong with my Boolean expression?

Tags: boolean-algebra, wolfram-alpha

I've got the following expression:

```
A*!B*(!B*C+!C*A*(D+B*!A+D*A*B+C*!D))
```

After translating it to Wolfram's understandable language I got this:

```
A OR NOT B OR (NOT B OR C AND NOT C OR A OR (D AND B OR NOT A AND D OR A OR B AND C OR NOT D))
```

For some reason Wolfram shows me this message:

```
Wolfram|Alpha doesn't understand your query
Showing instead result for query: OR
```

What's wrong with it? Why Wolfram can't minimize this expression?

Comment: It could be an input length issue. Wolfram Alpha cannot parse arbitrarily long statements and has built-in cutoffs as far as I am aware.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Yep, you're right, just checked that. A AND A AND A AND A doesn't work, but A AND A AND A does work :/ Too bad, it would help me a lot if there was a good Boolean expression minimizer somewhere out there

Answer (score 1):

Actually I got it working by using the proper notation:

```
A && ~B && (~B && C || ~C && A && (D || B && ~A || D && A && B || C && ~D))
```